# Connect LiPo battery to Arduino Motor Driver Shield for RC Boat

Tags: arduino, motor, battery, lithium-polymer, usv

Thanks for taking the time reading this question! It is greatly appreciated.

**What are we doing**
We (two complete noobs) are building a remote controlled boat from scratch using Arduino compatible components. With a hull created of paper-foarm soaked in glue and expoxy we aim to create a sturdy vessel capable of carrying a can of beer at a reasonable speed across the local waters.

**What are we trying to use**
Using an Arduino UNO for the boat, Arduino Nano for the remote control (housed in a modified PS4 controller body) and a bunch of sensors, OLED screens and NRF24L01 transceivers we have gotten the basics and some fancy extra's sorted.

However we are unsure about our most crucial components. After some failed attempts we have discovered we need a motor with enough torque or/and a gearbox to be able to propel our vessel within actual water. These higher specced motors also require a beefier power source and thus we've been looking into LiPo-batteries. This is where we got stuck!

Our research has brought us to selecting the following components:

- 2x RS PRO Geared DC Motor, 7.98 W, 6 → 15 V, 78.4 gcm, 9869 rpm, ~1A
  operating, 5A Stall current @
  https://docs.rs-online.com/216e/A700000007670040.pdf
- Cytron 10A 7-30V Dual Channel DC Motor Driver Shield MDD10 @
  https://www.robotshop.com/media/files/content/c/cyt/pdf/cytron-10a-7-30v-dual-channel-dc-motor-driver-shield-datasheet.pdf
- Gens Ace Soaring 2200mAh 14.8V 30C 4S1P Lipo battery - XT60 plug
- 2x ACS712 ACS712ELC Current Sensor Module 5A
- Avio Max Pro 04 20W Lipo charger

**Specific questions**
Primary:

- How do we connect the LiPo battery to the Motor Driver Shield in a safe manner?

Secondary:

- Can the LiPo be connected using a XT60 to Dupont cable?
- Is the motor torque of 78.4 gcm / 784 ncm at 9869 rpm sufficient for water movement?
- Do we even need the current sensor modules?
- Is the charger correct for this battery?
- Any other recommended H-bridge or Motor Driver that supports near 10A?

Tertiary:

- Shoot any holes into our plan - any and all suggestions welcome!

Comment: are you planning to turn the propeller at 9800 rpm?

Comment: @jsotola yes, if the torque is enough those high rpms make the boat go fast? Please correct us :)

Comment: A google search on ‘typical rpm of a boat propeller’ indicates 9800 rpm may be on the high side. The specific propellor you use (e.g., it’s pitch and diameter) will have a big impact on the desirable rpm range.

Comment: @RowanP how much torque do you think we need per motor? A very rough estimate would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You connect a battery to the shield via the power input terminal as described in the data sheet you [linked](https://www.robotshop.com/media/files/content/c/cyt/pdf/cytron-10a-7-30v-dual-channel-dc-motor-driver-shield-datasheet.pdf). Refer to figures 1 and 4, and table 1.

Comment: But how do we physicially connect it? The battery has an xt60 plug, the shield takes direct wiring plugged to those screws? Thanks!

Comment: One option is to cut of the XT60.

Comment: Another option would be to solder a short tail to an XT60 socket. Use that as an adapter between your battery and the shield power input.